# Не устанавливается текст в textview активити при вызове функции из фрагмента

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Нужно установить при активации, смене фрагмента свой для каждого фрагмента текст в textview, которое находится в toolbar'e активити.
В MainActivity (в конце):

```
fun fragmentTitle(ft: String) {
        binding.tvFragmentName.text = ft
    }
```

В FirstFragment (в onViewCreated):

```
(activity as MainActivity).fragmentTitle("титл")
```

Но приложение просто не запускается или вылетает. Хотя ошибок в коде АндроидСтудио не показывает.
Лог:

> --------- beginning of crash 2022-07-10 03:25:51.733 14693-14693/ru.jurvrn.sid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: ru.jurvrn.sid, PID: 14693
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.jurvrn.sid/ru.jurvrn.sid.MainActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41 in
> ru.jurvrn.sid:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #9 in
> ru.jurvrn.sid:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41 in ru.jurvrn.sid:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #9 in ru.jurvrn.sid:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
>      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in ru.jurvrn.sid:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
>      Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
>         at ru.jurvrn.sid.MainActivity.getBinding(MainActivity.kt:32)
>         at ru.jurvrn.sid.MainActivity.fragmentTitle(MainActivity.kt:100)
>         at ru.jurvrn.sid.FirstFragment.onViewCreated(FirstFragment.kt:66)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2985)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:532)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:259)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1327)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2757)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2693)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2986)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:375)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:258)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:295)
>         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:274)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1263)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
>         at ru.jurvrn.sid.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:76)
>         at ru.jurvrn.sid.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:70)
> 2022-07-10 03:25:51.733 14693-14693/ru.jurvrn.sid E/AndroidRuntime:  
>   at ru.jurvrn.sid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:40)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
> 2022-07-10 03:25:51.743 14693-14693/ru.jurvrn.sid I/Process: Sending
> signal. PID: 14693 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас код примерно такой:

1. В активити, в onCreate инициализируется переменная binding
2. После этого из неё устанавливается разметка в активити примерно так: `setContentView(binding.root)`
3. В разметке активити указан фрагмент в котором и происходит вызов метода, в котором идёт обращение к активити и вызов её метода, требующего проинициализированной переменной из п1

При этом вы наблюдаете ошибку, возникающую из вызова метода, обращающегося к переменной, которая ещё не инициализирована. Видимо, фрагмент в разметке дёргает активити в процессе инициализации `binding` переменной. По идее должен помочь перенос вызова метода активити из фрагмента в метод `onResume`

Comment: ваш ответ - это было решение. Но также работает вариант если код поместить в onStart. Судя по теории (https://otus.ru/nest/post/1649/) onStart и onResume у фрагмента запускаются не в строгой последовательности... Но так как по смыслу "старт" идет раньше "продолжения" наверно лучше в нем размещать для более раннего отображения текста? *** И можно вопрос по теории - в чем отличие  (activity as MainActivity).fragmentTitle  от  (requireActivity() as MainActivity).fragmentTitle ? Что правильнее? Что быстрее?

Comment: Еще проблема в том, что происходит видимая задержка в отображении текста (уже после отрисовки фрагмента)

Comment: Я бы фрагмент вообще программно бы отображал и заголовок из активити бы ставил. Ну или даже вообще из активити убрал бы заголовок, тулбар каждый раз свой рисуя в каждом фрагменте. Так бы не понадобилось из фрагмента активити вообще трогать. requireActivity, если глянуть в исходники (насколько помню) вызывает тот же getActivity, просто добавляя проверку на null и кидая ошибку, если оно так. Т.е. это просто синтаксический сахар для конкретно этого метода для конкретно котлина. Быстрее будет, конечно, getActivity, но, конечно, лучше использовать requireActivity - код красивее будет.

Comment: дело в том, что текс названия у фрагментов длинный - нужно его поместить полностью, а в две строки можно сделать тексn только в textView. Фрагмента 2. Какого-либо решения кроме добавления textView не нашел. Стандартный toolbar только в одну строку отображает и текст сокращается

Comment: Описанное вами никак не мешает разметку верхней части экрана (условно назовём её тулбар, не имея в виду что это одна из гугловых реализаций оного) поместить отдельно в каждом фрагменте и убрать её из активити. Тем более что фрагментов всего 2

Comment: понял, взял на заметку, но у меня в toolbar'e ещё ActionBar (c тремя точками). Его придется дублировать в каждом тулбаре каждого фрагмента? И немного не понял - быстрее `activity as MainActivity` чем `requireActivity() as MainActivity` ?

Comment: По поводу тулбара - всё очень зависит от того что вам нужно и как. Можно, например, сделать базовый фрагмент и в нём настроить меню. Потом от него наследуете другие ваши фрагменты и меню там уже будет. Можно и в активити оставить, но по моему опыту - проблем и неудобств от этого больше, чем от дублирования функционала во фрагментах. Про быстрее - да, по идее первый вариант быстрее. Но настолько незначительно, что точно **стоит не обращать** на это внимание. На таких вещах вы экономию близкую к нулю получите.

Comment: спасибо, подробно объяснили, этот вопрос закрыт